# Filter array of associative rows to retain only rows with unique value in specified column

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, filtering

I have the following array:

```
$array = [  
    ['id' => 1, 'code' => '342'],
    ['id' => 2, 'code' => '765'],
    ['id' => 3, 'code' => '134'],
    ['id' => 1, 'code' => '999'],
];
```

Here `Array[0]['id']` and `Array[3]['id']` are duplicates with respect to ['id']. I want to remove one of them (doesn't matter which).

Actually I thought I found a solution with this code:

```
//data
$row = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$ids = array();
for($i = 0;$i < count($row); $i++ )
{
    if (in_array($row[$i]['id'], $ids))
        {
            unset($row[$i]);
            continue;
        }

    $ids[] = $row[$i]['id'];

}

print_r($row);
```

For some reason it works well with small arrays, but if I have a lot of values in it with multiple duplicates, it fails. Any suggestion to what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution using regular `foreach` loop:

```
$rows = [
    ['id' => 1, 'code' => '342'],
    ['id' => 2, 'code' => '765'],
    ['id' => 3, 'code' => '134'],
    ['id' => 1, 'code' => '342']
];

$ids = [];
foreach ($rows as $k => $item) {
    if (in_array($item['id'], $ids)){
         unset($rows[$k]);            
    } else {
         $ids[] = $item['id'];
    }    
}

print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done without looping. Let me show an example:

```
$rows = array (
    array ('id' => 1, 'code' => '342'),
    array ('id' => 2, 'code' => '765'),
    array ('id' => 3, 'code' => '134'),
    array ('id' => 1, 'code' => '342')
);

$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $rows)));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($input);
```

Output:

```
 Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [code] => 342
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [code] => 765
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [code] => 134
    )

  )
```

Comment: thanks for feedback, actually I missed something in the question, damn, Sorry ! I need to point out it is not a complete duplicate (wow, I was sleeping). It is only 'id' that is the duplicate or `$row[$i]['id']` in my example

Comment: The sample data in the question was edited to better represent the project data after this answer was posted.  This answer no longer work as desired with the OP's changed data.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove one of them (doesn't matter which).

Okay, use `array_column()` to assign temporary first level keys using the `id` values.  Because PHP will not allow two elements in the same level to share the same key, each subsequent duplicate will overwrite the earlier encountered row.  Wrap that call in `array_values()` to remove the temporary keys (re-index the array).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/d4dQf))

```
var_export(
    array_values(array_column($rows, null, 'id'))
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'code' => '999',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'code' => '765',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'code' => '134',
  ),
)
```